# Complex sqlQuery

Tags: mysql, sql

Database-MySql

Following is the create table statement.

```
CREATE TABLE `Test`( `T` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,`P` varchar(40) NOT NULL,`CT` char(1) DEFAULT 'V',`XY` char(1) DEFAULT 'A');
```

In above table there are 3 columns (T, P, CT,XY).
1.In column 'T' and column 'P' has relation such that values of both the columns will make pair. Any value in the pair  will not make pair with other values of other column.
2. column CT has 3 type of possible values ---> V,W,X. 
3. column XY has 3 type of possible values ---> A,B,C.

Data in the table is as following.

```
1. insert into Test values('T1','P1','V','A');
2. insert into Test values('T1','P2','V','B');
3. insert into Test values('T2','P3','V','C');
4. insert into Test values('T3','P3','V','A');
5. insert into Test values('T4','P4','V','A');
6. insert into Test values('T4','P4','V','A');
7. insert into Test values('T4','P4','V','B');
8. insert into Test values('T4','P4','W','A');
9. insert into Test values('T4','P4','X','A');
```

Output will be only one rows -- T4,P4,2

Explanation

```
1. First row will be discarded because of T1 is making pair with 2 values(P1,P2)of Column 'P'.
2. Second row will be discarded because of T1 is making pair with 2 values(P1,P2)of Column 'P'.
3. Third row will be discarded because of P3 is making pair with 2 values(T2,T3)of Column 'T'.
4. Fourth row will be discarded because of P3 is making pair with 2 values(T2,T3)of Column 'T'.
5. Output will be pair of T4,P4
```

Third column of output will be derived as for a pair(T4,P4) , count the number of instances where column 'CT' value is V and column 'XY' value is A. There are 2 instances (as u can see in row5 and row6), so third column of output will be 2.

I tried using the query but it is not giving me correct result.

```
select T,P,sum from (select T,P,sum(if(CT = 'A' and XY = 'B',1,0)) sum from Test group by T,P ) X group by T having count(*)=1;
```

what will be the Sql Query to solve above problem?

Comment: Can you try a simpler explanation of how you are trying to choose the rows?

Comment: and also a better context of the purpose of what this is being used for.  Trying to make "generic" can sometimes prevent due to loss of context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first four items in your explanation of how output is produced can all be satisfied by using aggregate queries to find, and exclude, cases where either `T` or `P` is duplicated among all unique combinations of `T` and `P`, as is done in the subqueries here:

```
select
    t.T, t.P, count(*) as rows
from
    Test as t
    left join (
        select T from (select distinct T, P from Test) as p1 group by T having count(*) > 1
        ) as dupT on dupT.T=t.T
    left join (
        select P from (select distinct T, P from Test) as p2 group by P having count(*) > 1
        ) as dupP on dupP.P=t.P
where
    dupT.T is null
    and dupP.P is null
    and CT = 'V'
    and XY = 'A'
group by
    t.T, t.P;
```

This is a fairly literal interpretation of your criteria, discarding bad data, but you can also carry this out by *including* only the good data:

```
select
    t.T, t.P, count(*) as rows
from
    Test as t
    inner join (
        select T from (select distinct T, P from Test) as p1 group by T having count(*) = 1
        ) as dupT on dupT.T=t.T
    inner join (
        select P from (select distinct T, P from Test) as p2 group by P having count(*) = 1
        ) as dupP on dupP.P=t.P
where
    CT = 'V'
    and XY = 'A'
group by
    t.T, t.P;
```

Comment: Many times 'Test' table is iterating, Can it be minimized?

Comment: If your version of MySQL supports CTEs, then pulling out the repeated subquery `select distinct T, P from Test` into a CTE *might* improve performance. You could check this using the `EXPLAIN` command to check the query plan with and without this change.  Indexes on `T`, `P`, `CT`, and `XY` may also improve performance.